# How can an understanding of the ARMv7 Architecture lead to more efficient Java/Android code?

Tags: android, jvm, armv7, instruction-set

I am watching many videos and reading some articles on `RISC` and `CISC` architectures and [Computer Architecture](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5PHm2jkkXmi5CxxI7b3JCL1TWybTDtKq) in general.

To my limited understanding, one major difference between `RISC` and `CISC` is:

> each RISC instruction roughly translates to a single operation that
>   the CPU can perform.

Knowing this; and other `RISC` specific features: what design decisions should an Android developer consider that are different from traditional Java development?

For example:

Let's say I want to multi-thread syntax highlighting on the users' search terms on a List of results.

One idea is to have a pool of size `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` and each task in the pool work on an individual element in the array.

I can use an `OrderedSet` to maintain order, by making each element in the list an object which implements `Comparable` and provide some sorting in `compareTo`

I am **not an expert** so I can't really say that this is a good solution for this problem on a `CISC` CPU or some AWS EC2 instance.

I am also trying to improve my understanding, so would this still be a good design on a `RISC` processor? If not, why not? What is a better design decision?

What are some decisions to consider for `RISC` specific code that help improve the functionality by improving performance? Or has the new `ARMv7` too similar `CISC` making all this moot?

Comment: You don't try to optimize your code unless you have done some testing and found bottle knecks.

Comment: read http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano I agree with what you are saying in spirit, but I do have this code that is currently slowly loading a View.  So I have a need to optimize.  Maybe not in terms of CPU and rather in terms of algorithm, but I do have a need.  Since I have that need it is good to look at all options

Comment: dont get worked up about CISC and RISC and von neumann and harvard and other terms you may read.  the line between CISC and RISC is a bit blurry.  You should clearly see that CISC does multiple things per operation from a high level you can perform operations with memory operands for example in x86.  add some memory location, some value.  which means the memory location has to be read, the math done then the memory location done.  think of that is a read, an add and an write, three high level operations.

Comment: a RISCy view of that is perform a load, possibly move an immediate value into another register, do the add, then store the result out, taking multiple instructions, but instructions that flow through the processor much faster with much less logic.  just like computers use binary based gates rather than base 10 logic with 10 states per signal.  takes more gates but is so much more efficient (and accurate) that it makes sense.  CISCs have traditionally been microcoded in some way (there is another processor inside that is more risc like or even simpler) for various reasons.

Comment: at the end of the day though you are so far removed from most of this and you are trying to hard to make a connection that you fall into the pre-optmization.  doesnt mean you cant write your code to be more efficient and perform better, but you are just scratching the surface on this and need to do more research in particular compiling and disassembling to see what the tools are doing to your code as you change it.

Comment: JAVA is an abstraction it is its own instruction set that is interpreted by a virtual machine at runtime. (can be compiled to the target but often isnt).  So kinda by definition it is inefficient and slow.   but that is not the purpose the purpose was portability.  Write one program compile it to the virtual machine instruction set, and run everywhere, windows, mac, linux, etc.